# Generating simple music/tones?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, audio

I looked around Google and SO but couldn't find this....

Is there a way to generate simple tones (i.e. beeps, squarewave, sawtooth) using just the standard library of python on a mac?

Basically I'm playing with the idea of melody generation in a text rpg setting, so the music evolves with the player's stats, etc, in a simple way, with chiptune melodies, hopefully multi-channel.

Well, I'll cross that bridge when I get to it, but for now, I just need to know what I can and can't do in terms of "coding sounds". Is this a reasonably simple thing? Or is it more involved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more complicated than that, i think you have to add a package. Visit the [PythonInMusic page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) and go to 'Music Programming in Python'. It lists several packages that can be integrated to enable you to produce sounds in python.